# Show that $\frac{x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{y}{1-y}\cdot\frac{z}{1-z} \ge 8$.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

> If $x,y,z$ are positive proper fractions satisfying $x+y+z=2$, prove that  $$\dfrac{x}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{y}{1-y}\cdot\dfrac{z}{1-z}\ge 8$$

Applying $GM \ge HM$, I get $$\left[\dfrac{x}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{y}{1-y}\cdot\dfrac{z}{1-z}\right]^{1/3}\ge \dfrac{3}{\frac 1x-1+\frac 1y-1+\frac 1z-1}\\=\dfrac{3}{\frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z-3}$$

Then how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: :hi see this book 
Equations and Inequalities: Elementary Problems and Theorems in Algebra and Number Theory 
Jiri Herman , Radan Kucera (, Jaromir Simsa (Author)

Comment: The $GM>HM$ approach in this question doesn't work, because taking $x=0.00001$ ($y,z$ arbitrary to satisfy $x+y+z=2$) we get the RHS smaller than 2.

Comment: @A.D. Your approach cannot be followed. By Cauchy-Schwarz $\sum \frac{1}{x} \sum{x}\geq 9$, therefore $\sum \frac{1}{x}\geq 9/2$ whereas you need to show $\sum \frac{1}{x}\leq 9/2$

Comment: @S.B.: Ok. I understand that I am wrong. Then how I proceed?

Comment: @julien $x,y$ and $z$ are less than one.

Comment: @S.B. I see, that's what proper fraction means...Thanks.

Comment: @julien: Yes S.B. is right. They are positive proper fractions .

Comment: @A.D: Do you understand my solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write $(1-x)=a, (1-y)=b \text { and}  (1-z)=c$

$x=2-(y+z)=b+c$

$y=2-(z+x)=a+c$

$z=2-(x+y)=a+b$

Thus we have the same expression in simpler form:

$\dfrac{b+c}{a} \cdot \dfrac{a+c}{b} \cdot \dfrac{a+b}{c}$

Now we have AM-GM:

$b+c \ge 2 \sqrt{bc}$

$a+c \ge 2 \sqrt{ac}$

$b+a \ge 2 \sqrt{ba}$

$\dfrac{b+c}{a} \cdot \dfrac{a+c}{b} \cdot \dfrac{a+b}{c} \ge \dfrac{2^3 abc}{abc} =8$, Done.

Comment: $\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}$ I don't understand why you use $+$ . I think it is $\cdot$ i.e. product not sum.

Comment: Ah. Typo. Rectified.

Answer (score 3):

Two proofs of the inequality have been posted. The following is simply a comment. In the attempted solution of the OP, the inequality
$$\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{y}{1-y}\cdot \frac{z}{1-z}\right)^{1/3}\ge \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-3}\tag{1}$$
has been proved.

One can complete things by showing, under the hypothesis $x+y+z=2$, that the right-hand side of (1) is $\ge 2$.

However, that is not true. For instance, take $x=\frac{5}{6}$, $y=\frac{5}{6}$, and $z=\frac{2}{6}$. Then 
$$ \frac{3}{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}-3}=\frac{18}{10}\lt 2.$$

So too much has been given away in producing (1): there is probably no direct path from it to the desired result.

Comment: Ok. I understand that my procedure must not work. Then how can I solve the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

We begin by setting $a=1-x, b=1-y, c=1-z$, and noting that $a+b+c=1$.  The conditions of the problem imply that $a,b,c\in (0,1)$.

We now need [Maclaurin's inequality](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC4/Handouts/inequal/node6.html): $$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge \sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3}}\ge \sqrt[3]{abc}$$

Ignoring the middle part temporarily, we have $\frac{1}{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{abc}$ or $3\sqrt[3]{abc}\le 1$.  Ignoring the first part and squaring, we have $\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3}\ge (\sqrt[3]{abc})^2\ge 3abc$, where we multiplied by $3\sqrt[3]{abc}\le 1$ in the last step.  We rearrange this to get $$ab+bc+ac\ge 9abc$$
then rearrange that to get $$1-a-b-c+ab+bc+ac-abc\ge 8abc$$
The left side factors as $(1-a)(1-b)(1-c)$; divide by $abc$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks.Can you help me to show this inequality $\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge \sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+ac}{3}}$. Otherwise I understand your answer.

Comment: @A.D: Square both sides, you will have a final expression $a^2+b^2+c^2-ac+bc+ab \ge 0 $, multiply the whole equation by $2$, you will see $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0$, which is true.

Comment: @Inceptio : Thanks. But again typo mistake $-ac+bc+ab$ . I think here + will be -.

Comment: No, it will be $a^2+b^2+c^2-(ac+bc+ab) \ge 0$, the day isn't good for me.

Comment: This is [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin's_inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are sides of a triangle. Let $p$ be half the perimiter (i.e., $p=\left(x+y+z\right)/2=1$). Then you'd like to show that $xyz\geq 8(p-x)(p-y)(p-z)$. From geometry we know that $xyz = 4RS$ where $R$ and $S$ denote the radius of the circumcircle the area of the corresponding triangle. Furthermore, $p(p-x)(p-y)(p-z)=S^2$ by Heron's formula. Therefore, we have to show that $$4RS\geq 8S^2/p$$ or equivalently $$R\geq 2S/p.$$ Considering the fact that $S=pr$ where $r$ is the inradius of the triangle, the last inequality is equivalent to $R\geq 2r$ which is a well-known geometric inequality ([Euler's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem_in_geometry)).